# Error Deploying to Sandbox

Tags: deployment

Have you ever faced this kind of issue? is there a workaround for this? I haven't changed any of the files listed in those errors, the error message is not helpful at all.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Can you please [edit] the question to provide more context? How are you deploying this metadata? What sort of sandbox is it? If you are using sfdx CLI have you tried enabling debug for the CLI tool itself? Do you see any logs on the org for when this fails? Anything else you can provide to help us help you can only improve your chances of getting an answer. Worth reading [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well, since your question doesn't show any effort at research or problem solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should look at you triggers on content. This seems to be a custom error. You can verify it by disabling triggers on content in Files settings.

Setup > Salesforce Files Settings.

- Skip triggers execution when deploying asset files
- Skip triggers execution and validation rules on asset files

Enabling the settings may not be right depending on your requirement.